# Find offset and eof file into another file

Tags: java

Good Morning. There is a file, which contains several images inside it. How do I get the byte chain between two points I have. For example:

Bytes of my file

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 
44 52 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 40 08 02 00 00 
00 25 0B E6 89 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 
00 0E C4 00 00 0E 49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82
```

Code Java

```java
byte[] header = new byte[] {(byte) 0x89,
                            (byte) 0x50,
                            (byte) 0x4E,
                            (byte) 0x47,
                            (byte) 0x0D,
                            (byte) 0x0A,
                            (byte) 0x1A};

byte[] endBytes = new byte[] {(byte) 0x49,
                              (byte) 0x45,
                              (byte) 0x4E,
                              (byte) 0x44,
                              (byte) 0xAE,
                              (byte) 0x42,
                              (byte) 0x60,
                              (byte) 0x82};

RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("MY FILE", "r");
```

From this point forward I don't know how to proceed.

How do I get the byte string contained between the header and the endBytes ?

Comment: Well, keep reading until you run into the end bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 7 there is class `java.nio.file.Files` which has [static] method `readAllBytes()`. That method has a single parameter which is the path to the file to read and returns a `byte[]` array that contains the entire file contents. So no need for `RandomAccessFile`.

You want all the bytes in the file apart from the first seven and the last eight. The following code demonstrates.

```java
/*
 * import java.nio.file.Files;
 * import java.nio.file.Paths;
 */
try {
    byte[] readBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("datafile.dat"));
    byte[] requiredBytes = new byte[readBytes.length - 7 - 8];
    System.arraycopy(readBytes, 7, requiredBytes, 0, requiredBytes.length);
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```